# Papadimitriou's pseudopolynomial algorithm for m x n integer program with fixed m

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, linear-programming

Consider the following proof from Papadimitriou's "On the Complexity of Integer Programming":

---

**Corollary 1.** There is a pseudopolynomial algorithm for solving m x n integer programs, with fixed m.

**Proof.** We can solve the m x n integer program Ax = b by dynamic programming, proceeding in stages. At the jth stage we compute the set $S_j$ of all vectors $v$ that can be written as $v = \sum_{i = 1}^J v_ix_i$, with $v_i$ the ith column of $A$ and with the $x_i$ in the range $0 \le x_i \le B$ where $B = n(ma)^{2m+1}$. Since the $S_J$ cannot become larger than $(nB)^m$, the whole algorithm can be carried out in time $O((nB)^{m+1}) = O(n^{2m+2} (ma)^{(m+1)(2m+1)})$, a polynomial in $n$ and $a$ if $m$ is fixed.

---

I think $|S_J| \le (nB)^m$ since there are at most $nB$ vectors of the form $v_ix_i$. In the worst case, the sums of $m$ of them are all distinct. Thus, we would have $(nB) \cdot \ldots \cdot (nB) = (nB)^m$ possible outcomes.

But why does the "dynamic programming" algorithm run in $O((nB)^{m+1})$? In particular, should I not count the complexity of each operation (addition, multiplication, etc) involved?

It seems that there is missing information since in [later papers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.00481.pdf) citing this work, an explanation is given based on maximum weight path problems, but the obtained bound is not exactly the same (it is equivalent).